# Add a custom persistent provider to open jpa

Tags: java, jpa, openjpa

I want to know how to edit persistent.xml and add custom persistent provider . How can i add custom persistent provider.

Comment: An application has persistence.xml in which it specifies the persistence provider to use. A JPA implementation (openJPA) does not provide a persistence.xml. No idea what you're asking

Comment: I edited the question . I want to know how to add a custom peresistent provider

Comment: define what is a "custom persistence provider" to you. You mean your own JPA implementation (extending OpenJPA) ?

Comment: yes i want to add a custom persistent provider class

Comment: Hi Do you know any such example of doing that. What I want is to intercept entity beans without touching the entity beans source codes (i.e I have to put annotations if I add a event listener for an entity). So I though of writing a wrapper for the openjpa persistence provider implementation. Do you know any such places that has done this.Any links